# Laravel looses Session ( Authentication)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with a specific route on Laravel. Every second time (and sometimes on the first time) when ill call a specific route, ill get an 401 error, returned from the Authentication Middleware.

File Middleware/Authenticate.php

```
class Authenticate
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401); // THIS IS CALLED
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('login');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

From that route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
   .........
   Route::get('events', 'TaskController@events');
});
```

TaskController.php

```
public function events(Request $request) {

    $time_from = $request->start;
    $time_to = $request->end;

    $events = array();

    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    .....

    return response()->json($events, 200);
}
```

All called from a JQuery $.get Request. I dont know why Laravel thinks i am a guest, and then looses the Session?

Comment: run this command: `php artisan route:list` and check if the specific route is passing through the Web middleware, which handles the session.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing ajax/api requests laravel thinks you're guest because session based authentications doesn't apply to this type of calls. Whenever you use auth middleware you'll get 401 on ajax, even if you're authenticated.

You need some type of token based authentication for the ajax/api calls, that sends Authentications header on requests and new middleware that handles authentications for it.

Comment: I am authenticated. This is not running as a Service (like REST) - i am just doing a normal GET Request inside jquery (in an web-app)